# Erro unefined method acts_as_authentic for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Minha aplicação funcionava muito bem até hoje, mas agora ao iniciá-la apresenta este erro:

> erro unefined method acts_as_authentic for main:Object

Segue meu código do`act_as_authentic` no model de usuário:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.login_field = "coluna"
end
```

Estou utilizando Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2 e Authlogic 3.4.3

Comment: acredito que essa informação é útil:
app/models/user.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `current_user_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:14:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:27:in `require_no_user'

Comment: o que mudou entre o código que funcionava para o que parou de funcionar?

Comment: eu excluí o projeto e comecei do zero, já que estava no começo, não tenho certeza mas é possível que tenha corrompido meu application_controller.rb